# Trying to convert matrix code from MATLAB to Python, is this correct?

Tags: python, matlab, matrix

I've got a longer code which I'm trying to convert from matlab to Python and I think for the most part it's correct but I'm not getting the same output as the matlab code. I believe the problem is to do with the matrix A because I've been fiddling around with the code to try and identify it, but I also can't see anything wrong it.

Matlab:

```
m=250
beta=0
alpha=0.25
A=zeros(m,m);
A(1,1)=1-2.*alpha; A(1,2)=2.*alpha;
A(m,m)=1-2.*alpha; A(m,m-1)=2.*alpha;
for i=2:(m-1)
     A(i,i-1)= alpha+beta ; A(i,i)=1-2.*alpha ; A(i,i+1)=alpha-beta; 
end
```

Python:

```
import numpy as np
m=250
Beta=0
Alpha=0.25
A=np.zeros(shape=(m,m))
A[0,0]=1-2*Alpha
A[0,1]=2*Alpha
A[m-1,m-1]=1-2*Alpha
A[m-1,m-2]=2*Alpha
for i in range(1,m-1):
     A[i,i-1]=Alpha+Beta
     A[i,i]=1-2*Alpha
     A[i,i+1]=Alpha-Beta
```

It may that the problem is somewhere else in the code, in which case I'll keep looking - but could someone check if this is correct for me? Thanks!

Comment: So, if you run these two pieces of code by themselves, do you get a different output? How do the outputs suffer? Showing that would make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: Sorry, I don't actually have matlab which is my main problem. I've just got a copy of the code on notepad and I know what the final output should be at the end.

Comment: Then get Octave (free!) and run the MATLAB code there. Most MATLAB code will run there unchanged.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look on there and see if I can solve it.